# ubuntu 16.10, unity: cannot login into computer after it goes to sleep

Tags: lock-screen

Machine goes to sleep, I come back hours later and mouse/keyboard does nothing. Cannot login.
I can ssh in from another computer and gracefully reboot.
Am using the nouvea driver for the video card.
Machine is not a laptop.
I am not using suspend.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to work if I don't lock the screen. Still testing.

Answer (score 0):

I must be an outlier. I was using the default nouveau display driver and changed it over to the nvidia 367.57 driver.
No longer am having an issue with screen lock.
Never experienced this before and I have been using ubuntu since warty.
Hope this helps someone else...